Firebase sign out permissions error in android application?
I am getting permissions error every time i try to log out in kotlin android project which uses firebase firestore and firebase auth.  I am even terminating DB when try to sign out and it still doesn't help
 if (auth.currentUser != null) {
    Button(onClick = {
        coroutineScope.launch {
            listenersManagerViewModel.removeAllListenersAndTerminateDatabase()
            auth.signOut()
        }
    }) {
        Text(text = "Sign out", style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleMedium)
    }
}

In ListenersManagerViewModel:
fun removeAllListenersAndTerminateDatabase() {
    listeners.forEach {
        it.remove()
        database.terminate()
        database.clearPersistence()
    }
}

I am getting such fatal error:

PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.

FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: com.example.taskmaster, PID: 32344
com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.Util.exceptionFromStatus(Util.java:113)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.EventManager.onError(EventManager.java:247)

Terminating database and clearing it persistance, removing listeners

MAYBE THE USER DO NOT HAVE ACCESS TO DELETE OR REMOVE SOMETHING FROM THE DATABASE .

@Rudra i double checked that user has permission to do so, if i mark signOut in MainActivity it works perfectly

IT WILL BE BETTER TO DEBUG CODE IF YOU PROVIDE THE FULL STACK TRACE OR THE LINE FROM WHERE ERROR OCCUR ALSO KEEP THE CLEARPERSISTENCE IN AN TRY-CATCH BLOCK

@Rudra: Using all-caps is perceived as YELLING in online communications. Please only use caps to emphasize short bits of your messages where needed.

@Ivan: the error message you get from the database is pretty explicit: some of your code is trying to access data that it isn't authorized to. And since this happens when you sign-out, it's most likely you have a lingering listener that you forgot to remove (i.e. could it not be in listeners?). Given the code you shared that is all we can say though.

What is the exact line of code that throws that error? Please respond using @AlexMamo
